# Appending rows to an existing table (titanium)

Tags: titanium-alloy

```
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        chatId : data.chat_id,
        title: 'New Account ',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        selectedBackgroundColor : 'transparent',
        selectionStyle : 'Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE on createTableViewRow',
        width : '100%',
        height : '60'
    });


    $.tableview.appendRow = row;
```

doesn't seem to be working, despite following docs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appendRow is a method not a property, so you have to change:

```
$.tableview.appendRow = row;
```

to:

```
$.tableview.appendRow(row);
```